# How can i extract specific string from a text?

Tags: c#

I have a file that i edit with notepad, example of some of the file content :

ionTrigger_1_Deactivated":false,"bWL1TwoSwitchesArrived":true,"E1_WL1_HangingBedsA_M.TheWorld:PersistentLevel.GppInteractionTrigger_0_Deactivated":false,"E1_WL1_HangingBedsA_M.TheWorld:PersistentLevel.GppInteractionTrigger_1_Deactivated":false,"bHangingBedsASaved":true} !   m_WhatLevelPlayerIsAtEncodedJson    ArrayProperty T          L   {"currentLevelName":"E1_WL1_HangingBedsA_M","currentLevelEntryDirection":8} &   m_WhatCheckPointPlayerIsAtEncodedJson    ArrayProperty {          s   {"hasCheckPoint":true,"LocX":19873.1816,"LocY":2330.6631,"LocZ":-299.1126,"RotPitch":0,"RotYaw":81508,"RotRoll":0}    None    m_SubtitlesDisplayed
BoolProperty            None

what i want to extract as a string is this part :

currentLevelName":"E1_WL1_HangingBedsA_M"

the problems are how to extract it and that in each file the currentLevelName is different.
in this file the currentLevelName is E1_WL1_HangingBedsA_M but in another file for example the name is : E1_WL1_HallwayDragonFace_M

i want to loop over all the files and in each file to extract that part.
and when extracting the currentLevelName i want to change the current file name to that level name for example if the first file in the loop is : savedGame001

then in the loop the first file name should be renamed to : Current Level Name_E1_WL1_HangingBedsA_M

Comment: I guess that data is JSON, although it's hard to say whether it's valid or not because you've made no effort to format it for readability. In that case, you need to spend some time learning how to work with JSON in .NET. Basically, the JSON data will be parsed into one or more objects and you then get your data from those objects.

Comment: Did you try with `RegEx`?

Comment: @sallushan not yet tried with regex i need to try regex. until now i used indexof and substring. the problem is when i'm trying to read the file content with File.ReadAllText i'm getting one symbol and not all the content like i'm editing it with notepad.

Comment: @DubiDuboni, that's another problem actually, reading the data and not getting all the data is one problem, while changing the text is another, so I guess you need to post separate question for that.

Comment: @sallushan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73431425/how-to-extract-specific-string-from-a-text

Answer (score 1):

If the text in your file is in JSON format i suggest use the **Newtonsoft.Json** package from **nuget**. You can deserialize the json to a dynamic object using

```
dynamic myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("filename.json");
```

Comment: I tried and getting exception : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0.'
 all the files are the same type and name KQSave that's the file name and exmaple of the file content when editing with notepad : https://pastebin.com/j1diF8f3 i'm not sure if it's json format.  i can edit it in notepad but can't get it as text by code.

Comment: I tried it like this : files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\\Win\Saved Games", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            for(int i = 2; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                dynamic myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(files[i]);

Comment: Have you tried either saving the file with a leading '{' bracket or pretending the value '{' ahead of the string you read from the file? Without a correctly formatted json value, Newtonsoft will fail at parsing it for you. You'll also need '}' at the end

Comment: it seems to be working mym istake i will delete the q.

Comment: @user3439632 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73431425/how-to-extract-specific-string-from-a-text